# Remove nodes in object JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, attributes

I have the following:

```
[{
  'another@exemple.org': {
    'age': 42,
    'prefered_color': 'blue',
    'hate': 'flowers'
  }
}, {
  'another@exemple.org': {
    'age': 45,
    'prefered_color': 'red',
    'hate': 'burgers'
  }
}]
```

I want to put the key variable (email address) to the same level to get the following:

```
[{
    'email': 'another@exemple.org',
    'age': 42,
    'prefered_color': 'blue',
    'hate': 'flowers'
  },

  {
    'email': 'another@exemple.org',
    'age': 42,
    'prefered_color': 'blue',
    'hate': 'flowers'
  }
]
```

I tried different things (map, expends) but I am actually wondering what is the most efficient way to get the result above.

Thank you for discussing.

Comment: Use `map`. [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/feLhtef7/) **Code:** `arr.map(function(e) {
    var email = Object.keys(e)[0];
    e[email].email = email;
    return e[email];
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new array using the [`.map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and retrieve the email value by getting the key of the object:

```
var newArray = array.map(function(obj) {
  var key = Object.keys(obj);
  obj[key].email = key[0];
  return obj[key];
});
```

#### Example:

```js
var array = [{
  'another@exemple.org': {
    'age': 42,
    'prefered_color': 'blue',
    'hate': 'flowers'
  }
}, {
  'another@exemple.org': {
    'age': 45,
    'prefered_color': 'red',
    'hate': 'burgers'
  }
}];

var newArray = array.map(function(obj) {
  var key = Object.keys(obj);
  obj[key].email = key[0];
  return obj[key];
});

document.querySelector('pre').textContent = JSON.stringify(newArray, null, 4);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```